# File reading with and without new line

Tags: c++, scanf, eof

In terms of an input file reading,

- I found

  ```
  for (i = 0; !inStream.eof() ; i++) inStream >> input[i];
  ```

  tries to read one more time if there is a "new line" at the end of file.

  ```
  for (i=0; inStream >> input[i]; i++ ) ;
  ```

  seems to work whether there is a new line or not at the end of file .

  Are there any other neat solution for handling a "new line" at the end of file ?
- in c, I write

  ```
  FILE *fp = fopen("file", "r") ;
  for (i=0; fscanf(fp, "%d", & input[i]) > 0 ; i++ ) ;
  ```

Are there any way I can use `fscanf` with c++ input file stream not using `fopen()` ?

Comment: Regarding `for (i = 0; !inStream.eof() ; i++)  inStream >> input[i];` see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ library provides you with a handy `getline` function. Here is a minimal example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com)

```cpp
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer+knowledge. 8)

Answer (score 0):

> any way I can use `fscanf` with c++ input file stream?

Possibly. Both `g++` and Visual Studio have had their own extenstions making it possible. If you find such possibilities, they are non-standard and not portable. I advice you to find other ways.

If you use C++, try to use the most of it. `C` does have `fscanf` which looks neat - but it's a beast. C++ has `std::scanf` for portability - and it's the same kind of beast. Don't use it if you are programming C++.

The problem you're trying to avoid

> `for (i = 0; !inStream.eof() ; i++) inStream >> input[i];`
>   tries to read one more time if there is a "new line" at the end of file.

is caused by improper use of `eof()`. `eof()` returns `true` *after* you've tried to read beyond end of file. A better loop would look like:

`for (i = 0; inStream >> input[i] ; i++);`

Notice how the extraction and condition became one? They aren't. The extraction happens first and returns the *stream* used in the extraction. The stream has a `bool` overload that tells you if it's in a failed state or not, making it great for this kind of checking: `if(stream >> variable) { /* success */ } else { /* fail */ }`.

This only works if your array has entries enough to store all input though. Your loop does not check that. If you use a `vector` you can just read elements and `push_back` to make it work a long long time. If you have a fixed (relatively small) size and do the above, it'll fail eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer+knowledge. 8)

Comment: @JohnP Cheers! Hope it helps!